# Clear checkbox in reactjs hooks after submitting

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I have a few separate checkboxes in a form. But I have no idea how I could clear the checkboxes after submitting it.

```
const App = () =>{

   const funct1 = (e) => {
      if(e.target.checked){
      //some function
      }
   }

   const funct2 = (e) => {
      if(e.target.checked){
      //some function
      }
   }

   const funct3 = (e) => {
      if(e.target.checked){
      //some function
      }
   }
   const submitForm= (e) => {
      //some function
   }
   
   return(
      <div>
         <div>
            Pear <Checkbox onChange={(e)=>funct1(e)} />
         </div>
         <div>
            Apple <Checkbox onChange={(e)=>funct2(e)} />
         </div>
         <div>
            Orange <Checkbox onChange={(e)=>funct3(e)} />
         </div>
         <Button onClick={(e) => submitForm(e)}> Submit </Button>
      </div>
   )
}
```

I have read about `useRef`, but I am not sure how it can help me in this situation. Can anyone explains to me if it is possible to use `useRef` in this situation to help me achieve what I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

## Uncontrolled solution

Simply add an `<input type="reset">` element and HTML will clear everything in the form

## Controlled solution

Keep the checkboxes' values as react state, and reset them in the submit handler:

```js
const [check1, setCheck1] = useState(false)

<Checkbox value={check1} onChange={e => setCheck1(e.target.checked)} />
```

Comment: any example on the controlled solution? right now what I am using to perform calculations are based on `e.target.checked`. I have updated my code

Comment: You're defeating the whole architecture of react, you should always keep state in react's hooks or use `setState()` in class components. Added a small snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You *control* the value of checked through state. you start off uncheck ie: `useState(false)`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function Form() {
 //  initialize your checkbox value
 const [pear, setPear] = useState(false);

 function handleSubmit(){
  // use the pear variable instead of the event values
  // do your submit logic, i would assume some ajax call to a backend. 
  fetch('/myFormSubmitEndpoint')
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => setPear(false)) //here you will do all your "reset" logic AFTER your submit has succeeded
   .catch(...)
 }

 return (
   <form>
     <label>
       Pear
       <input
        checked={pear}
        onChange={e => setPear(!pear)}
        type="checkbox"
        name="pear" />
    </label>

    <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
  </form>
 );
} 
export default Form;
```

Comment: it doesn't work. now my `setPear` value after first click is true, hence the next time it re-renders, it's still true

Comment: @jason1234 Ah, i see you want to clear it after submit, I updated the example